# How to migrate to CouchDb from goleveldb on IBM Blockchain cloud sandbox

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I used these [instructions](https://ibm-blockchain.github.io) to setup a Blockchain network on the IBM Container Service's free plan. But it by default connects to leveldb. How can I migrate it to a CouchDB so that I can do complex Queries?
Right now with leveldb, When i implement Queries and calls it i get the following error

> {
>     "error": {
>       "statusCode": 500,
>       "name": "Error",
>       "message": "Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb)",
>       "stack": "Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: ExecuteQuery not supported for leveldb)\n    at channel.queryByChaincode.then.catch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:782:34)"
>     }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix starter plan does not allow to modify network configuration. So spinning a couch db instance while bootstrapping is not an option.
If chaincode is written in go and struct are defined with docStructure:

type marble struct {
    ObjectType string `json:"docType"`
    Name       string `json:"name"`
    Color      string `json:"color"`
    Size       int    `json:"size"`
    Owner      string `json:"owner"`
}

Blockchain service will automatically spin a couch db instance

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what kind of access your IBM account for blockchain offers, let me answer it from a Fabric perspective. 
You need to spin up 1 CouchDB container per peer(there are images for hyperledger-fabric-couchdb), and change peer config so that 1)statedb is CouchDB and 2) give the address of CouchDB container to peer.
All these can be done via changing the docker compose file (assuming you are using one) 
Please see http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html#using-couchdb for more specific details.

Comment: I have the same problem and this does not even remotely address the issue. It basically says you should use Couch where the question is basically how do I use couch on BlueMix.